# Specifying metadata for input formats other than Markdown

Tags: pandoc

Pandoc allows you to include metadata at the beginning of a Markdown document using a header like

```
---
title: The Song That Never Ends
subtitle: It Goes On and On My Friends
author: Abraham Lincoln
lang: en_US
---
```

Is there any way to convey this information to Pandoc when the input format is *not* Markdown? I’m specifically interested in HTML input. I tried calling Pandoc with `--from=html+yaml_metadata_block`, but this didn’t seem to change the behavior at all—the YAML block is just interpreted as HTML.

(It is possible to include some metadata in the “percent format” shown in [the “pandoc_title_block” section of the manual](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-pandoc_title_block), but there doesn’t seem to be a way to give a separate title and subtitle with that syntax. It’s also possible to include the YAML header before the HTML and to force Pandoc to interpret the input as Markdown, but this seems hacky, and if you try to convert that to “real” Markdown then the output is full of HTML tags instead of Markdown formatting characters.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `--metadata` (short `-M`) or `--metadata-file` [options](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#reader-options) to supply metadata on the command line, for example:

```
pandoc -M title="The Song That Never Ends"
```

Comment: This isn’t *exactly* what I asked for but it’s actually a better and more elegant solution than what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to use Lua filters to augment the metadata read from the HTML file as [described in the Lua filters doc](http://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#default-metadata-file). Below is an updated version:

```
-- file: additional-metadata.lua

function read_file_as_markdown_yaml (filename)
  -- read metadata file into string
  local metafile = io.open(filename, 'r')
  local content = metafile:read('*a')
  metafile:close()
  -- get metadata
  return pandoc.read(content, 'markdown').meta
end

function Meta (meta)
  -- read YAML file and add its content to the metadata
  local yaml_meta = read_file_as_markdown_yaml(meta.default_meta_file)
  for k, v in pairs(yaml_meta) do
    -- use YAML metadata as fallback
    meta[k] = meta[k] or v
  end
  return meta
end
```

Use with

```
pandoc --lua-filter additional-metadata.lua \
       --metadata default_meta_file:YOUR-FILE-HERE.yaml \
       your-input-file.html
```